# Can/How do I link to a dll (at runtime) and withhold admin rights from it?

Tags: windows, security

I am working on a C++ win32 API program. In some situations, the program must be launched with admin rights to work correctly.

I'm adding support for third-party extensions - dlls that users can drop into the program's folder. My program scans for these dlls at runtime, links to them, and occasionally calls specific functions from them. I'm concerned that users could receive malicious extensions that could do serious damage with admin rights.

Thus, I want to runtime link to the dlls and not let them have admin rights even if my main program has admin rights. Can/How do I do this?

Comment: You can't. DLLs are loaded into your process, and it's already running elevated, so the DLLs are running in that elevated process. The DLL has the same elevated privileges. Your program could simply not load the extensions if it's running with elevated privileges (disabling use of extensions when running as admin).

Comment: Loading foreign code into your process always poses a security risk, running elevated or not. Your only safe option is to somehow sandbox that code, to confine damage, e.g. by moving it to a different process.